# Jersey Test starts HTTP server twice

Tags: java, web-services, http, testing, jersey

I have issue with HttpServer in Jersey tests. If i include all the tests in one it works fine, but if I have two or more then, after passing one of them it throws **exceprion javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: IOException thrown when creating the JDK HttpServer Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind.** 
Debug shows that it tries to start server one more time. How fix this bug?
Thanks in advance.

This is my configuration for

```
public class SomeJerseyTest extends JerseyTest {

@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
    return new JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory();

}


@Override
protected Application configure() {

    System.setProperty(IDBPoolConstants.PROP_POOL_URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ets_test");
    final HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    when(request.getAttribute("ets")).thenReturn(TestUtils.loginAsSU());
    return new ResourceConfig().register(UpdateReportResource.class).register(ReportResource.class).register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(request).to(HttpServletRequest.class);
        }
    });
}

 @Test
 public void testPutTexStatusOk() {
    TexStatusDTO dto = new TexStatusDTO();
    dto.setAuthor("Padme Amidala");
    dto.setCode(3);
    dto.setDescription("testPutTexStatusOk");
    dto.setReportId(11);
    dto.setCreated(new Date());
    Response response = target().path("reports/texStatus").request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .buildPut(Entity.entity(dto, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).invoke();
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

 @Test
 public void testCode200 () {
        final Response response = target("/reports/reports").queryParam("projectId", "63").request().get();
        System.out.println(response);
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
 }
```

**Stacktrace**

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: IOException thrown when creating the JDK HttpServer.
at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:262)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:206)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:111)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory$JdkHttpServerTestContainer.<init>(JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory.java:82)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory$JdkHttpServerTestContainer.<init>(JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory.java:67)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory.create(JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory.java:125)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.createTestContainer(JerseyTest.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.setUp(JerseyTest.java:609)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:100)
at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:50)
at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:129)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:259)
```

Comment: Can you post the code with multiple tests? So we can check it.

Comment: I posted test, but without DB it wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.createTestContainer(JerseyTest.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.setUp(JerseyTest.java:609)

These methods (setUp() and createTestContainer()) are missing. That's where you are getting the error. Can you update the answer with the whole test class that's not working?

Comment: Aurasphere, this is the whole class. Maybe you need others?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that as you said the container is instantiated twice. You could probably easily get around this using the singleton pattern:

```
private JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory containerFactory;

@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
if(containerFactory == null) containerFactory = new JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory(); 
return containerFactory;
}
```

Just add this field and change the getTestContainerFactory method and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help, but thanks for trying.

Comment: Well, it's black magic, because i've created a new file, copied everything there and it works fine.

Comment: Good to hear that!